# Best way to secure MMCX jack-to-jack adaptors?

Tags: connector, wireless, interconnect

I'm currently using an MMCX jack-to-jack adaptor to connect a wire from a transceiver to another wire from an antenna.

Through this adaptor, the wires click into it.
However, I would like to better secure this connection, giving more inward push as shown in the picture below.

Are there standard solutions for this?

[image]

Comment: cable ties ....

Comment: Slips off too easily...

Comment: You could always heatshrink it on for a more permanent but not permanent installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a lack of standard solutions for this exact situation (securing the MMCX connector), my solution ended up being a 3D printed clip, designed with [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of these types of these splice connectors that have a cable gland on both ends.  When you tighten the cap on either end, it squeezes a ring of plastic fingers together which in turn compress a rubber sleeve around the cable and maintain a slight inward pressure.  You'll just need to find one in the correct cable diameter range or build up your cable with heatshrink.

Picture from: [https://www.amazon.com/Waterproof-Electrical-Junction-Connector-External/dp/B07V5L2RZ8?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V5L2RZ8)

[image: Junction splices]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this would work with securing the MMCX connectors, but it may be still be useful for other similar situations.